# Hudson/Jenkins: Start task simultaneously on multiple slave machines

Tags: hudson, build-automation, jenkins

If I have a task (a script) that needs to start on n number of machines at the same time (with some tolerance: ~10 minutes), how do I go about setting this up in Hudson or Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they all the same type of machine (OS?)

You can use a multi-configuration style job. This will run the script on all the machines you specify under "slaves".

If they are not all the same (for eg mix of Linux and Windows), you may need to come up with either a platform independent script - like ant, or install bash on Windows so you can use "Execute Shell"

Comment: Yes, all machines run Win7. I am looking up multi-configuraion jobs right now.

Comment: Great. In that case, you can use the "Execute Windows Batch Command" and put your script there, or use it to call your script directly.